# Laravel 8 - Form action redirect to 404 page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have gotten an error (404 - NOT FOUND) when I want to send some data from the form, and I have a check on the controller, the route, and the view many times.

- Admin click on the button to change the status’s post from Approve to
  Reject, or it does the opposite.

---

**PostController.php**

```php
   public function changeStatus(Post $id){
            $status_update=new Post;
            $status_update->findOrFail($id)->status->get();
            if ($status_update ==1){
                $status_update->update(['status'=>0]);
                session::flash('message', 'It has been updated');
                return back();
    
            }elseif ($status_update->status==0){
                $status_update->update(['status'=>1]);
                return back();
    
            }
      return back();
        }
```

**The Route:web.php**

```php
 Route::middleware('role:admin')->group(function (){
        Route::PATCH('supervisor/{$id}/update',[PostController::class,'changeStatus'])->name('admin.posts.changeStatus');
    });
```

**The view**

```php
<form method="post" action="{{route("admin.posts.changeStatus",$post->id)}}">

   @method('PATCH')
   @csrf
  @if($post->status==1)
  <button type="submit" value="0" class="btn btn-gold">change status to reject  </button>

@else 

 <button type="submit" value="1" class="btn btn-primary">change the status to approve
 </button>

   @endif
    </form>
```

Comment: route parameters don't have `$` in their name ... `supervisor/{id}/update`

Comment: @lagbox Yes, you alright, I remove the `$` from the route, and it's work now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem with @lagbox. Thank you @lagbox.
and the solution of my issue that shows in the route: web.php.

> route parameters don't have $ in their name ... supervisor/{id}/update